# How to get plan.id from Stripe

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I create the plan first. All's good. I create customer next. all's good.
I next try to create subscription, like this:

```
Stripe::Subscription.create(
  customer: @customer,
  source: params[:stripeToken],
  item: [{ plan: plan.id }]
```

And that results in an error undefined local variable or method `plan'

The item bit is required, and the hash within angle brackets is what's shown on the Stripe api.  Any help would be most appreciated!

Comment: It sounds like you don't have a `plan` object defined. You can either retrieve your Plans to find the one you're looking for using [Stripe::Plan.list](https://stripe.com/docs/api/plans/list?lang=ruby) or view your existing plans in the Stripe Dashboard (under Products) and get the `id` value from there.

Comment: did you pass plan id as params ? cuz I do not see it

Comment: @taintedzodiac could you check my post plz? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54448040/form-tag-does-not-produce-stripetoken-upon-submit

Comment: taintedzodiak, Yes the plan I created is good. I now need to immediately use that plan.id to create the subscription. That is where I am failing. Product good. Plan good. Subscription not good. And that's because I don't know the syntax for attaching the good plan to the subscription. The docs suggest item: [{plan: plan.id }] but I get the undefined local variable or method error with that.

Comment: Kick Buttowski, perhaps you could show me the syntax for doing that? Can you correct my Stripe::Subscription.create ? Keep in mind this the user is to complete this process in one action. In other words, I am not creating a plan on the dashboard and then capturing the id for that plan. It's designed to be a seamless one-transaction entry. Customer comes to website, signs up for a subscription with a unique plan and effects the first payment and so on.

Comment: Could be unrelated, but should `item` be in fact `items`? [see here](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/create) for an example request.