# form_tag does not produce stripeToken upon submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I am following [this tutorial](https://stripe.com/docs/recipes/variable-amount-checkout) for having customized checkout button

I changed the tutorial for my need, and when I check my params , stripeToken is empty

> {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"sometokenvalue",
>   "stripeToken"=>"", "amount"=>"40000", "item_id"=>"3"}

I suspect I get this error

> Invalid source object: must be a dictionary or a non-empty string. See
>   API docs at https://stripe.com/docs'

owing to that.

my code as follows :

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12"><p>
      <strong>Name:</strong>
        <%= @item.name %>
      </p>  
      <p>
        <strong>Price:</strong>
        <%= @item.price %>
      </p>

       <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"></script>

      <%= form_tag item_charges_path(@item, amount: @item.price), id: 'paying-form' do %>
          <% if flash[:error].present? %>
            <div id="error_explanation">
              <p><%= flash[:error] %></p>
            </div>
          <% end %>
        <article>
        </article>
        <article>      
          <%= hidden_field_tag :stripeToken  %>
        </article>
        <button id='donateButton' class='btn btn-primary'>Pay</button>
      <% end %>

        <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_item_path(@item) %> |
        <%= link_to 'Back', items_path %>


          <script>
            var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
              key: '<%= Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key] %>',
              locale: 'auto',
              token: function(token) {   
                $('input#stripeToken').val(token.id);
                $('form').submit();
              }
            });
          </script>
          <script>
          document.getElementById('donateButton').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
              //e.preventDefault();

              $('#error_explanation').html('');

              var amount = "#{@item.price}";
              amount = amount.replace(/\$/g, '').replace(/\,/g, '')

              amount = parseFloat(amount);

              if (isNaN(amount)) {
                $('#error_explanation').html('<p>Please enter a valid amount in USD ($).</p>');
              }
              else {
                amount = amount * 100; // Needs to be an integer!
                handler.open({
                  amount: Math.round(amount)
                })
                e.preventDefault();
              }
            });

            $(window).on('popstate', function() {
              handler.close();
            });

          </script>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Note:** I put the js codes in the same page for simplicity goals.

Could anyone tell me what is wrong that my form does not produce stripeToken?
or May be I am missing some points?

**Note:** please if more info is  needed,let me know so I post
Thank you

Comment: This isn't really a Rails or Ruby question since it doesn't go through rails in any way except page generation. Post the generated HTML, and remove the ruby-on-rails tag please.

Comment: Also, it may be easier to use javascript to submit this form instead, via the fetch() api.

Comment: @SkamanSam   that is a good point. should I add page generation after submit or before submit? and regarding to your second comment, I am just following the tutorial and for simplicity I gonna stick to it for now.

Comment: A first step to troubleshooting might be to try commenting out or adding a breakpoint before ` $('form').submit();` , then double check with your browser inspector that your `stripeToken` input is populating with a token value.

Comment: @duck does not it token being created upon clicking on the  button? and as I showed in my post , no it does not get populated with a token value which is my issue here

Comment: The token is created upon submitting the 'checkout' form. It's mostly a question of if the value of the token is actually populating your input which you then submit as part of your <form>

Comment: @duck lets chat here https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187604/stripe-payment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in your JS:

```
var amount = "#{@item.price}";
```

...should instead be...

```
var amount = <%= @item.price %>;
```

Then, move the following code at the top just below the line: `addEventListener`

```
e.preventDefault();
```

Then, remove the following because you don't need it anymore because the `@item.price` comes directly from your database:

```
amount = amount.replace(/\$/g, '').replace(/\,/g, '')
amount = parseFloat(amount);
```

Lastly, because `amount` is guaranteed to be correct and has an Integer value, then you don't need the following anymore and so remove them:

```
if (isNaN(amount)) {
  $('#error_explanation').html('<p>Please enter a valid amount in USD ($).</p>');
}
```

*don't forget to remove the dangling `} else { }` code*

### Explanation:

- If my understanding is correct upon looking at your code, whenever you click the "Donate" button, because of the typo, your `if (isNaN(amount))` basically evaluates to `if (isNaN("#{@item.price}")` (which is a STRING!!!), and this is why `isNaN("#{@item.price}")` always equals `true` (because it's Not-A-Number!), and therefore the `else` condition which is...

  ```
  handler.open({
    amount: Math.round(amount)
  })
  e.preventDefault();
  ```

  ...never gets called. Take note that the `e.preventDefault()` above never gets called! ...which means that your form submits "the normal way" without opening up the "Stripe" modal. If my theory is correct, this is why `:stripeToken` is empty string because the default  value for your `hidden_tag :stripeToken` is empty-value which means `''`, instead of the correct way: which is that after you click the Donate button, the Stripe modal should pop up, and after the Stripe transaction has been completed, the `token` function callback will be called:

  ```
  token: function(token) {   
    $('input#stripeToken').val(token.id);
    $('form').submit();
  }
  ```

  ...of which as you would see  above, will update your `stripeToken` input to have the correct "token" value. And then also as you could see above, the form will then be submitted but now the `stripeToken` input now has a value because you just updated it.

*P.S. Haven't used Stripe per se*

Comment: thank you and I did changes , yet I still have the same issue. 
As I said, I just followed the tutorial e.preventDefault() was used there

Comment: Yes, you are supposed to use `e.preventDefault()` but in your code above you commented it out.

Comment: If it still does not work, then this perhaps is another separate problem. Let's se...what happens when you click "Donate"? Do you get the Stripe modal pop up?